# How to check if a certain property is undefined in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api, server

I am building my own server with NodeJS and PostgreSQL. For a specific API I execute a query and I need to know if a certain property of the result is undefined or not. What I did is this:

```
pool.query('SELECT id, administrator FROM public."user" WHERE uid = \'' + admin + '\'', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
       throw error
    }
    if (results.rows[0].administrator !== undefined) {
       // do my stuff
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work, it returns me this:

```
if (results.rows[0].administrator !== undefined) {
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'administrator' of undefined
at /home/mauro/secure-door-server/api/controllers/secureDoorController.js:27:25
at Query.<anonymous> (/home/mauro/secure-door-server/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:348:18)
at Query.handleReadyForQuery (/home/mauro/secure-door-server/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:128:10)
at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/mauro/secure-door-server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:244:19)
at Connection.emit (events.js:223:5)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/mauro/secure-door-server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:128:12)
at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How can I check such property?

Comment: `results.rows[0]` is `undefined`, not `results.rows[0].administrator`. As the error says you are trying to use the `.administrator` property *from the value `undefined`*.

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks.  Use a proper parameterized query!

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can Check this way

```
if (results.rows && results.rows[0].administrator) {}
```

**OR** *for better result you can check this way*

```
if (results && results.rows && results.rows.length && results.rows[0].administrator) {
   //Your Code
}
```

Comment: Yeah thank you! This solutions seems to work properly

Comment: @spike32 most welcome, you should mark the answer has correct if solution solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

What you did is right, you only need to check whether results have rows in it and that's why results.rows[0] is getting undefined in your code. Something like

`if (results && results.rows && results.rows[0] && results.rows[0].administrator !== undefined)`

will be working fine.

Comment: One of the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

you can use "hasOwnPropety"

```
if (results.rows && results.rows[0].hasOwnProperty('administrator') {}
```

It will return true if the property exists.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution helps a lot too!